# docker compose by ssh not copying files

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose

I am trying to use docker in a remote server using docker context. My project is really simple, just an apache server managed by the docker-compose.yml. This YML file has been tried in the remote server copying the files and running the command docker-compose up there. Everything works well doing it like this.

The problem I am facing is when I try to run this using this ssh option of the docker context. For some reason, the files are not transferred to the remote machine.

The client machine is a Windows server 2019:
[image: Image server settings]

The remote server is an ubuntu server in the same network.

I have tried sharing the C folder with everyone.
[image: Image of shared folder]

I don’t know why but when I inspect the files inside of my container I see this asterisk where it should be the files I want.
[image: Image folder with an asterisk]

This is the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  php:
    image: bitnami/php-fpm:latest
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    working_dir: /
    volumes:
      - .:/app
  apache:
    image: bitnami/apache:latest
    ports:
      - 80:8080
    working_dir: /
    volumes:
      - ./apache-vhost/myapp.conf:/vhosts/myapp.conf:ro
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - php
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Host volumes are always local to the host where docker is running. This is the same when you run from the docker CLI, within swarm mode, or as you're seeing in docker-compose. There's no real solution to make this work with a host volume because it gets to the fundamentals of how Linux does a bind mount.

To redesign this, consider using a named volume and either populating that volume from an image or docker I/O redirection. E.g. here are some commands to import/export volumes using tar and docker's I/O redirection with a temporary container that would run on the remote host:

```
# import data
tar -cC source_dir . | \
  docker run --rm -i -v target_vol:/target busybox tar -xC /target

# export data
docker run --rm -v source_vol:/source busybox tar -cC /source . | \
  tar -xC target_dir
```

Comment: Thank you @BMitch , I am not very expert in all this DevOps and docker world. You're reply looks a bit advanced for me. Do you have any link where I can read more about this topic? or some keywords?

Comment: @JuanGarcía docker has general docs on volumes here. I'm posting what feels like the easy option to me, as opposed to managing an nfs server. https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/